# PHP disable caching for specific header?

Tags: php

I'm wanting to send a response header with PHP, but I don't want that specific header to be cached by browsers.

Is there any way to specific a header and disable caching it, but still cache everything else as usual?

Answer (score 0):

You can instruct the browser in terms of caching behaviour using `Cache-Control` header, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) docs. But, that beeing said, you cannot instruct it on specific headers. That is the kind of logic that a CDN or a caching server like Varnish would implement and is not something you will do in PHP.